# Trigger href tag on click parent div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML code is given below:

```
<div id="appoint" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10 new-appo-margin">
            <h2><a href="#" data-target="#bring_food4" data-toggle="modal" class="trigger_class">Dallas Allergy and Asthma Center</a></h2>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="bring_food4" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>We found an existing appointment at this office! Would you like to order food for this appointment?</h1>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h2 class="pad-left-as">Mon June 06</h2>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <h1>Dallas Allergy and Asthma Center</h1>
                                            <h2>Lunch - 9:13AM</h2>
                                            <h2>Sugg. Order Count: 10</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button class="secondary_btn" data-target="#cancel_order4" data-toggle="modal" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/52">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="cancel_order4" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>You will need to schedule an appointment before ordering food at this office !</h1>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/52">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">84/4, 2nd Floor, Shahi Majra, Phase-5, Cellulosics Rd, Phase 3, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab 160055</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="non-lunch-logo-img text-right">
                <img src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10 new-appo-margin">

            <h2><a href="#" data-target="#bring_food6" data-toggle="modal" class="trigger_class">Harmony heart center</a></h2>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="bring_food6" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>We found an existing appointment at this office! Would you like to order food for this appointment?</h1>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h2 class="pad-left-as">Tue June 14</h2>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <h1>Harmony heart center</h1>
                                            <h2>Lunch - 12:00 PM</h2>
                                            <h2>Sugg. Order Count: 12</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button class="secondary_btn" data-target="#cancel_order6" data-toggle="modal" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/61">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="cancel_order6" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>You will need to schedule an appointment before ordering food at this office !</h1>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/61">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">phase 5 Newyork abc, abc 0123</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="non-lunch-logo-img text-right">
                <img src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 new-appo-margin">
            <h2><a href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/policy/index/24">Aaberg MD</a></h2>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">84/4, 2nd Floor, Shahi Majra, Phase-5, 234234</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 new-appo-margin">

            <h2><a href="#" data-target="#bring_food31" data-toggle="modal">Dhayan singh</a></h2>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="bring_food31" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>We found an existing appointment at this office! Would you like to order food for this appointment?</h1>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h2 class="pad-left-as">Tue July 05</h2>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-0 col-sm-2">
                                            <img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <h1>Dhayan singh</h1>
                                            <h2>Dinner - 1:00pm</h2>
                                            <h2>Sugg. Order Count: 0</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button class="secondary_btn" data-target="#cancel_order31" data-toggle="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/29">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="cancel_order31" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>You will need to schedule an appointment before ordering food at this office !</h1>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/29">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">84/4, 2nd Floor, Shahi Majra, Phase-5, 234234</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 new-appo-margin">
            <h2><a href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/policy/index/33">Dhayan singh mola</a></h2>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">84/4, 2nd Floor, Shahi Majra, Phase-5, 234234</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 new-appo-margin">
            <h2><a href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/policy/index/42">test</a></h2>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">test 5455</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10 new-appo-margin">

            <h2><a href="#" data-target="#bring_food9" data-toggle="modal" class="trigger_class">Chaitanya hospital all hospital facilities</a></h2>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="bring_food9" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>We found an existing appointment at this office! Would you like to order food for this appointment?</h1>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h2 class="pad-left-as">Wed June 08</h2>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <h1>Chaitanya hospital all hospital facilities</h1>
                                            <h2>Lunch - 12:30pm</h2>
                                            <h2>Sugg. Order Count: 0</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button class="secondary_btn" data-target="#cancel_order9" data-toggle="modal" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/68">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="cancel_order9" class="modal fade">
                <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body full_div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <h1>You will need to schedule an appointment before ordering food at this office !</h1>
                                    <div class="row margin_top">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="secondary_btn" type="button">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="primary_btn" href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/order/policy/68">Yes</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">84/4, 2nd Floor, Shahi Majra, Phase-5, Cellulosics Rd, Phase 3, Industrial Area, Sector 58, mohali, punjab 160071</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="non-lunch-logo-img text-right">
                <img src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-15px non-lunch-p-h">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-center"><img width="50" alt="" src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/office_icon.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-10 new-appo-margin">
            <h2><a href="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/rep/policy/index/7" class="trigger_class">Beli  hospital with emergency</a></h2>
            <p class="font_p_14 font_24px-color">test test, test 89541</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="non-lunch-logo-img text-right">
                <img src="http://orphcnul.com/lunch-pro-dev/assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using given below string :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.non-lunch-p-h').click(function(){
        $("a.trigger_class").trigger('click');
    });     
});
```

But it gives me an error:

> Error: Stack overflow, too much recursion

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because the `.trigger_class` elements are contained within the `.non-lunch-p-h` element. This means that the `click` event that you trigger bubbles up the DOM from `.trigger_class` back to `.non-lunch-p-h` and fires another click, which bubbles up the DOM, which fires another click... and so on, hence the Stack Overflow exception.

To fix this you should either use `stopPropagation` in the `.tigger_class` click event handler:

```
$('a.trigger_class').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // your code here...
});
```

Or alternatively (and more preferably in my opinion) is to call a function in both cases instead of creating event which the user did not explicitly create:

```
$('.non-lunch-p-h').click(doSomething);

$('a.trigger_class').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the modal do that..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.non-lunch-p-h').click(function(){
        $("#bring_food6").modal('show');
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple elements that match the selector

```
$("a.trigger_class")
```

You only want to trigger the *a.trigger_class* contained inside the element the user clicked.

So you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.non-lunch-p-h').click(function(){
        $(this.currentTarget).find("a.trigger_class").trigger('click');
    }); 
});
```

**BUT** this way you are triggering a click event in an element which is contained inside *.non-lunch-p-h*. This cause a recursion. So you want to change your code this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.non-lunch-p-h').click(function(){
        var hrefVal = $(this.currentTarget).find("a.trigger_class").attr('href');
        document.location = hrefVal;
    }); 
});
```